# Adjust table view size for iPhone 3.5inch keeping the same amount of cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

I have a static table view that i set up in story board, targeting iPhone 5. The table view takes up the full screen for iPhone 5 (`Height = 568`) and the TableView has 11 cells. When this is run on the iPhone 3.5 inch only 9 of the cells show. Is there a way using autolayouts or another to have the cell heights adjust so that all 11 cells show on the screen regardless of the screen size. The cells were created statically in Storyboard. I want to be able to resize the cells based on screen size.

Don't hesitate to ask if something is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code to set based on the your cell height required.

```
     - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {

int intheight=(int )[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

        if(intheight==568)
            return 100;
        else
            return 80;



        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how could you have 11 rows with that snippet.

Comment: @Justafinger I resize the cells, my cell height is smaller than the dimensions above, mine are 50 for iPhone 5 and 35 for iPhone4

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this to your controller

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/11;
}
```